# display image from remote server in gridview (android)

Tags: android, gridview

I'm trying to display images in gridview, I fetched images from remote server by soap service "in ImageAdapter1 class, method:set_mThumbIds()" and get these images to display in class "collection_Items"
it doesn't work at all!
can any one please help me!
I want to fetch images from soap service and view them in girdview

ImageAdapter1 class is:

```
public class Image_Adapter1 extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    Handler handler = new String[30];    
    public String[] mThumbIds = new String[30];
    // Constructor
    public Image_Adapter1(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public void set_mThumbIds(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {                 
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
                String ACTION="http://tempuri.org/getImages";
                String URL="http://10.0.2.2:50284/WebSite2/Service.asmx";
                String METHOD="getImages";

                SoapObject Req = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER11);
                env.dotNet=true;
                env.setOutputSoapObject(Req);
                HttpTransportSE androidhttp = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                SoapObject Result = null;
                try
                {
                    androidhttp.call(ACTION,env);
                    Result = (SoapObject) env.getResponse();
                }
                catch (final Exception c)
                {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, c.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (Result != null)
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<mThumbIds.length; i++)
                    {
                        mThumbIds[i] = Result.getPropertyAsString(i);
                    }
                 }
                else 
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "there are no images",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
        }).start();

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        set_mThumbIds();
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 200));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mThumbIds[position]));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

and collection_Items class is:

```
public class Collection_Items extends Activity{

    Image_Adapter1 imgadptr = new Image_Adapter1(this);
    //___________________________________________________________
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.collection_items);

            GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
            gridView.setAdapter(imgadptr);

            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Collection_Item_Details.class);
                    i.putExtra("id", position);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
     public void logout(View view){
            startActivity(new Intent(Collection_Items.this, Main.class));
        }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What kind of problem are you getting?

Comment: I don't know what the problem
I try to display images in gridview by fetching links of images
but the app says "unfortunately the app has stopped"

Comment: give us some log, try to set breakpoints in your code to figure out in what line the app crashes.